# Replacing oven element, but spade connector is damaged

Tags: repair, oven

I have a Whirlpool AKP200/WH (https://manuall.co.uk/whirlpool-akp-200wh-oven/) and the main element stopped working. The grill element still works, and the oven lamp, etc.

So I took the element out to have a look and found that one of its two male connectors was burnt up.

I then bought a replacement element hoping to fix, but as I explored further, I found that the wire had fallen through a hole in the insulation between the oven cavity and the back of the oven, and so I had to take the oven out to get it back.

I then noticed that the female connector on this wire had burnt up too (the one connecting to the burnt up element connector). So not a simple element replacement as I'd hoped.

I guess I need to fit a new female connector to the wire. The oven is old and a bit crap, but it did the job fine. So I'm wondering whether it's worth pursuing a repair, given I've already bought the new element.

How easy a job is it to fit a new connector?  I assume it would have to be a high-temperature tolerant one?  Would a repair shop do this sort of job?

**Male connector burnt up (part of element)**

[image]

**Good male connectors on new element**

[image]

**Female connector burnt up (part of wire)**

[image]

**Stripped some wire to see if it was damaged**

[image]

**Oven from the rear.**

[image]

**Oven from the rear. Lid off.**

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Good photos!

This is a common mode of connection failure, and is easily fixed.

- Test the *old* element -- it may very well be OK.

  - Resistance between the two QC lugs should be, roughly, in the range of 20 to 40 Ω.
  - Resistance from either lug to the bare (scraped free of oxide) metal tube should be infinite (blinking, on many digital meters).
  - If those values are OK, the element is likely good to reuse.
- If the end of the male lug on the heating element needs to be cleaned up, carefully use a fine file or rotary grinding tool, while *holding the base of the lug*, to prevent the filing from wiggling the wire and shattering the ceramic insulator. It's acceptable if the lug is just a *bit* smaller than the other, when done.

  [image: Clamp lug (from OP photo)]
- Cut back and strip the burnt wire until it is shiny copper (or tinned copper, silvery). *If* the burnt wire is now too short to reach the element lug with some slack remaining,

  - Use high-temperature wire (preferably glass-fiber insulated, such as [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0CN1B2WZQ)) to extend the burnt wire. A somewhat heavier-gauge wire might be helpful.
  - Use high-temperature ceramic wire connectors for that connection, such as [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0937C4FKW).
- Use a high-temperature Quick Connect (QC), such as [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0071NC5NO), for the connection. Take extra care to ensure a tight crimp and a tight connection to the lug, again being careful of the ceramic insulator.

*Examples are for illustration only, and may differ from the specific size or other requirement needed.*

Why is this failure mode so common?

- Manufacturers use the smallest wires size that carries the current, **when parts are new**.
- Repeated heating/cooling cycles cause the connector to loosen on the lug, increasing resistance.
- When two resistors are in series, i.e., the heating element and the QC connection, raising the QC resistance causes more heat to be dissipated in that connection. The maximum would be half that of the circuit. With an element designed for 1,500 W, for example, 375 W would be turned to heat in that tiny connector. No surprise that it went up in smoke!

(On occasion, I've crimped a *short* bit of copper tubing around the connected lug, acting as a heat sink and reinforcing the connection -- **being very careful that there is *nothing* the connection can contact**.)

Comment: The photo is of the male connectors of the old element. I'll add pics of the new element for comparison...

Answer (score 5):

Speaking as somebody with a moderate amount of professional experience with crimped (spade etc.) connectors: this is just about the worst kind of repair imaginable.

You will need the /correct/ type of crimping tool, sized to the wire. Expect to pay several tens of pounds.

You will need to splice the new wire in with a crimped butt joint, forget about soldering. You should ideally go to somebody reputable like Farnell and look for something with a good temperature rating, and expect there to be a minimum order quantity.

You will need to cut the damaged wire back a /long/ way to get to a point where it's still copper coloured: any attempt to crimp onto it where it's still discoloured will fail. The connector will again obviously need to have a good rating, and again expect there to be a minimum order quantity.

In short, you can expect to pay a substantial amount for tooling and parts. You'd be far better off getting a spare wire from the manufacturer, or finding a local electrical company who could make one up and would guarantee their workpersonship.

You're obviously more than capable of fitting the replacement wire yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't really trust myself to fix the wire, so a replacement would be best. Interesting you mention the wire should be copper coloured. Clearly in my photo the wire is dark silverish. Does this mean that that part of the wire is damaged in your opinion?

Comment: 1. A good crimp tool is just a few US$. *Careful* use of the tool is more important than price. 2. The old wire was discolored, damaged by oxidation at a *very* high temperature and by and contact with the poor-quality original insulation, which appears to be a PTFE derivative, *not* glass insulated (chlorinated and fluorinated plastics decomposes at high enough temp, attacking copper). It might have been tinned copper, which looks silvery, or plain copper, but now it's useless, up to the point where it's shiny metal again. Strip back insulation until you see shiny metal.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik a simple soak in salt & vinegar solution, followed by a dunk in a (neutralizing) baking soda solution, would clean the wires sufficiently.  No need to strip insulation.

Comment: @PaulGrime yes, that's the characteristic colour of copper which has been oxidised by excessive heat. The heat almost certainly was caused by sparking as the spade connection degenerated, and once there is not easy to remove: at least without further weakening the copper conductors. This is something which I've tried to fix in the past: and failed, even with the correct crimp dies etc.

Comment: @Huesmann, that is an exceptionally bad idea. The point is to have a good electrical connection, using the **full thickness of the wire**, not to have a *pretty* connection. With so much corrosion, there is less copper left, the thinned wire would have *high resistance*, and would burn out again, quickly. One goes back far enough in the wire to find undamaged, full-diameter copper, or replaces the wire completely.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I agree with your point about PTFE: interestingly, I have just fixed a problem in my 3D printer where a degraded PTFE insert (which had definitely never been above 250C) was starting to stick to absolutely anything. However the point I was trying to make about the tool was that it is definitely not the kind of thing one will pick up from Halfords or B&Q, and together with proper wire etc. (/not/ cheap stuff from eBay) a DIY repair is likely to be expensive.

Comment: @Huesmann No. The base material is compromised, and a simple chemical process will not help. Apart from anything else, if any significant amount of material is removed it will no longer be possible to get a decent (professionally referred to as "gas tight") crimp, and the problem will recur.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik assuming it is PTFE rather than e.g. glass-reinforced silicone, I'm reminded of the old chemists' joke: you could tell who was investigating fluorine chemistry by watching the obituaries. It really can be nasty stuff when abused, and that includes things like PTFE-loaded lubricants.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd, yes... Derek Lowe wrote of concerns with (some more reactive) fluorine compounds: https://www.science.org/content/blog-post/things-i-won-t-work-dioxygen-difluoride, and PTFE non-stick coatings are being phased out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymer_fume_fever, where the *mildest* symptom is fever. See also https://edu.rsc.org/feature/the-discovery-of-fluorine/2020249.article

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd Further to DrMoishe Pippik's comment, it is worthwhile finding all the "Things I Won't Work With" posts.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Not to mention Charlie Stross's take on it https://www.tor.com/2012/07/20/a-tall-tail/

Comment: Downvoted for:  "You will need the /correct/ type of crimping tool, sized to the wire. Expect to pay several tens of pounds."

Comment: @MikeB You could have just pointed out that SE markdown uses * rather than / for "emphasis" - or did your downvote refer to something else?

Comment: @AndrewMorton  No, I meant that I massively disagreed with that statement. A shitty pair of pliers will do the job if one is careful, not that I would recommend that option, personally. An adequate crimping tool can be hand for a few quid.

Comment: @MikeB A "shitty pair of pliers" will MOST DEFINITELY NOT do the job adequately.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd  Why not? I've not had to do it for many years, but not aware of any issues when I did. Functionally, there's nothing special about crimping tools, they just make it harder to do a bad job.

Comment: @MikeB Because in the electrical engineering context a crimp or swage (they are distinct) is a "stored energy" connection. That is, when the metal is acted on by the tooling's dies it is not taken beyond its yield point: both the sleeve etc. of the connector and the wire which is being terminated still have some spring in them. Part of the result of that- and this is crucial in the context of stuff which is temperature cycled- is that the pressure at the contact surface will remain constant over the long term. Look, absolutely everybody has used "shitty pliers" for audio, but they're NBG here.

Comment: @MikeB Apologies for continuing my comment, which I do not because I have copious time but because this can impact on electrical safety. The point I'm trying to make is that the dies in a crimp tool must match the gauge of the wire, as must the type of connector (in low temperature contexts shown by the sleeve colour). If things end up too slack you don't have a good connection, and if they end up too tight it might start off OK but won't last. For that matter exactly the same principles apply to contact design, as well as a multitude of other areas such as making riveted and bolted joints.

Answer (score 2):

It's a straightforward repair, but you will need a crimping tool to match the terminal that you buy to replace this one.

What's in the other end of the wire? If it's another spade, etc, then you might find that the easiest solution is to take the broken wire to an appliance repair shop and have them make a new one to match.

Comment: Hi. Yes, there's another spade on the other end at the front of the oven, but I haven't been able to take the top of the oven off yet to trace the wires to the front of the oven.  There's one stuck screw that I'm in danger of chewing up with a screwdriver.

Comment: @PaulGrime Stuck screws that have been repeatedly heat-cycled can also shear. Penetrating oil (NOT WD-40) is your friend.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Do you have a recommended brand of penetrating oil?

Comment: This worked for me https://www.diy.com/departments/3-in-1-multi-purpose-oil-200ml/212270_BQ.prd

Comment: Oven lid now removed and I've taken out the damaged wire